# chrome.runtime.sendMessage is showing error "Message length exceeded maximum allowed length"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

When i am sending big size of json object from content.js to background.js usingchrome.runtime.sendMessage then showing error like :

[refer error image to see actual error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHglN.png)

Error is : Uncaught Error: Message length exceeded maximum allowed length.

if anybody know about how to increase sendmessage parameter maxsize in manifest.json file.

Content.js

```
var ServerPath = "http://localhost:62513/api/account";
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: 'POST',
        action: 'xhttp',
        url: ServerPath + "/rapdata",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: data, fileName: fileName })
    }, function (responseText) {
        //alert(responseText);
        console.log("response of call saverapdata method");
        /*Callback function to deal with the response*/
    });
```

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
    console.log("background js onMessage call.");
    var resp = "done";
    if (request.action == "xhttp") {
        debugger;
        //alert(request.data);url: ServerPath + "/rapdata",
        var ServerPath = "http://localhost:62513/api/account";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: request.url,
            data: request.data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
                //alert("Data: " + data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                debugger;
                console.log(response);
                ///alert(response.d);
            }
        });
        return true; // prevents the callback from being called too early on return
    }
});
```

Comment: Use blob constructor and URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: it's google chrome extension project. here error showing when sending data from content.js to background.js with big size of json object.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty obvious

Comment: Thanks, it's work with URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Hi, old thread but I have same issue. Would I create the Blob of data in content.js and then createObjectURL, then pass over the reference to background.js? Sifting through the documentation but can't find examples for Chorme extensions